# Strange characters after extension creating zip file in php

Tags: php, windows, iis, zip, php-ziparchive

when a zip file creation script is called the file created has some random characters at the end, Like this 'data.zip8Cp785Cd'

```
   $dir ='../data/data/';
$destination = $dir.'data.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
    echo "Error";
}
$zip->addFile('./data/data.txt','datafile.txt');
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Ignoring the `../data/data/` and `./data/data.txt` differences, the first parameter of `addFile()` should be a path not a path and file

Comment: When I test your code, it doesn't create random characters at the end, but doesn't generate zip file correctly. Then I do some change, it can work and generate data.zip without strange characters.

Comment: <?php
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
 $dir ='./data/data/';
$destination = $dir.'data.zip';


if($zip->open($destination,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
    echo "Error";
}

$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");
$zip->addFile('./data/data.txt',"datafile.txt");

echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
?>

Comment: @BruceZhang still it's adding some starnge character .